# How can I get this RegEx to work?

Tags: php, regex

I want this code to check if a element exists and then get the number of records inside the div.

html

```
<div id=myDiv>This table contains 5 records (3 seconds)</div>
```

php

```
$selector = new Zend_Dom_Query($response->getBody());
$nodes = $selector->query('#myDiv');

if (count($nodes) < 1) {
            $this->setValue(0);
            return;
        }

        $el = $nodes->current();
        if (preg_match('#(\d+[\d,]*)\s+result#i', $el->nodeValue, $matches)) {

            $number = str_replace(',', '', $matches[1]);
            $this->setValue(intval($number));
        } else {
            Zend_Registry::get('log')->err(get_class($this).': Unable to match response and regex.');
            $this->setValue(0);
        }
```

Right now it gets to the bottom $this->setValue(0), so it can find the element. There must be something wrong with the regex, and that's where Im clueless.

```
if (preg_match('#(\d+[\d,]*)\s+result#i', $el->nodeValue, $matches)) {
```

Comment: I understand that this is not an answer to your question, however a good resource for regex and testing is http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: I need to take some time and learn how to do this. Im on here to much looking for help. Thats tool looks useful. Thanks. Can you recommend any good books.

Comment: I suggest any of the O'Reilly series of books.  There are a couple of good ones.  http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1331219916&sr=8-1  As well as the pocket book http://www.amazon.com/Regular-Expression-Pocket-Reference-Expressions/dp/0596514271/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1331219916&sr=8-3  Sorry i couldn't be more help on your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML code does not contain anything that would match `#(\d+[\d,]*)\s+result#i`, the expression requires the string "result" to be present.

You probably want to change that word to "record". E.g:

```
/(\d+)\s+record/i
```